# How to trim $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Tags: php, url, header, texttrimming

After from processing i am sending the user on the previous page using:

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '?Add=Successful');
```

Now it sends me to my **add.php**:

```
http://localhost/add.php?Add=Successful
```

Again when i add one more data the header location passes the following:

```
http://localhost/add.php?Add=Successful?Add=Successful
```

What i want is to trim the header location till question mark:

Lets say something like trimming the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` till `?` and saving it into a variable so that if keyword `?` exists it should trim it again to `http://localhost/add.php` and then pass that variable into header location, so that it can become something like this:

```
header('Location: ' . $trimmedHeader . '?Add=Successful');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also use PHP [parse_url()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

```
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$trimmedHeader = $url['scheme'] . '://' . $url['host'] . $url['path'];
header('Location: ' . $trimmedHeader . '?Add=Successful');
```

Comment: All of you have given the answer and its working, but the problem is, its not passing the variable back along with header. Its passing this:-  `http://localhost/add.php` whereas i want to pass this:- `http://localhost/add.php?Add=Successful` again.

Comment: But this what is in my script pass this variable again: '?Add=Successful'.
What more do You need?

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/(.*)\?/',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'\1');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return you everything before the first question mark in the string.

```
$trimmedheader = array_shift(explode("?", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']));
```

Comment: All of you have given the answer and its working, but the problem is, its not passing the variable back along with header. Its passing this:-  `http://localhost/add.php` whereas i want to pass this:- `http://localhost/add.php?Add=Successful` again.

Comment: You said: `What i want is to trim the header location till question mark` That is what my script is doing. If you want to append "?Add=Successful" to your string, just add it at the end: `array_shift(explode("?", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) . "?Add=Successful"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$urlArray = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$newUrl = $urlArray['scheme'].'://'.$urlArray['host'].$urlArray['path'].'?Add=Successful';
header("Location: $newUrl");
```

This has been tested and works fine....

Comment: All of you have given the answer and its working, but the problem is, its not passing the variable back along with header. Its passing this:-  `http://localhost/add.php` whereas i want to pass this:- `http://localhost/add.php?Add=Successful` again.

Comment: Try concatenating outside the header line maybe (I know function returns in header strings foofs things up)